# Where to place Templates in angular-meteor?

Tags: angularjs, templates, meteor, meteor-blaze, angular-meteor

I am trying to declare a template in my angular-meteor app in a Client javascript file. 
I have this in my main angular controller which is in the client side.

[image]

I am using [blaze-template directive](http://www.angular-meteor.com/api/1.3.0/blaze-template) to bind blaze template syntax to the angular scope.

In my index.html I have a template as such:

[image]

And just below it I have `<blaze-template name="rappers"></blaze-template>`

However I get an error [image]

When I delete my template from the controller javascript file. The error goes away, thus leading me to think my Template call in the javascript side is erroneous. Is there an angular binding issue with the Template ?

*As a side note: I did try moving my  template to another html file with no luck either*

**I should probably rephrase or ask another question because the only reason I am trying to use Meteor Templates is so I can use Session.get methods to access my Server side Meteor.methods that access *spotify-web-api* data. If I can use** `return Session.get("playlist")` **in my angular controllers than I'd do it that way. Is there a way to do it the angular way instead of accessing Session data the meteor way of calling Templates like below.**
``

```
Template.tweets.helpers({
    rant: function () {
      return Session.get("tweets");
    }
  })
```

``
**My angular code works with some success but it only console.logs() the data**

```
scope.getElvis = function(){
    Meteor.call('getElvis',function(err,data){
      if(err){
        console.log('failed ', err)
      }
      else{
        console.log('success ', data)
      }
    })
 }
```

Comment: Can try moving the `Template` declaration out of the controller to be global?

Comment: Hey @Urigo thanks for your response. I have tried moving the Template out of the controller with no success. I should note, I am using meteor's angular package. After some googling, I found that [angular@=1.07](https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/issues/849) utilizes `<blaze-template>` and your package [angular-with-blaze](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/angular-with-blaze). So I decided to remove angular and install **angular-with-blaze**. However my app breaks completely.

Comment: Can you share a repo?

Comment: https://github.com/felicedeNigris/MixtapeForum

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I solved the issue.

I removed the `angular` package and installed `angular-with-meteor` package. I then prefixed my `.html` file with `.ng.html`

In my `.ng.html` file I included my `<blaze-template name="list"></blaze-template>` In a separate `blazetemplate.html` file I included my blaze template.

I was unaware that `angular` package was incapable of rendering blaze templates , so switching over to `angular-with-blaze` really did the trick.

I feel like [documentation](http://www.angular-meteor.com/api/1.3.2/blaze-template) does a great job of showing a working example, however doesn't explain in details which packages are capable of blaze templates.

Shout out to Uri and his team at angular-meteor.

Great link to follow if you are stuck. https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/issues/849

Answer (score 0):

Remove the existing blaze framework and try following

```
 meteor add angularui:angular-ui-router
```

For example you may refer the link below:

http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular1/routing-and-multiple-views

Comment: Hey @HarshMakadia I am using **angular-ui-router** and it is working great. I just would like to use blaze templates because I am using the [spotify-web-api](https://atmospherejs.com/xinranxiao/spotify-web-api) and Meteor.methods({ spotify get methods }) from the server. Then from the client javascript I want to use Templates to get the data from the server side  spotify api methods. I guess that should be saved for a different question.